# Get counts of values in column with hierarchical data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Category    Shuffled        Name     Sequence    Length
0        pgm           0    protein1         IAAI         4
1        pgm           0    protein2         PGGP         4
2        pgm           0    protein3         KIIK         4
3        pgm           0    protein4         PGGP         4
4        btn           0    protein1         ABBA         4
5        btn           0    protein2         IAAI         4
6        btn           0    protein3         ABBA         4
7        btn           0    protein4         PGGP         4
8        pgm           1    protein1         IAAI         4
9        pgm           1    protein2         PGGP         4
10       pgm           1    protein3         KIIK         4
11       pgm           1    protein4         PGGP         4
12       btn           1    protein1         ABBA         4
13       btn           1    protein2         IAAI         4
14       btn           1    protein3         ABBA         4
15       btn           1    protein4         PGGP         4
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of `Sequence` in each `Category`/`Shuffled` group and add it as a new column. The resulting data should look like this:

```
    Category    Shuffled        Name     Sequence    Length    Sequence_count
0        pgm           0    protein1         IAAI         4                 1
1        pgm           0    protein2         PGGP         4                 2
2        pgm           0    protein3         KIIK         4                 1
3        pgm           0    protein4         PGGP         4                 2
4        btn           0    protein1         ABBA         4                 2
5        btn           0    protein2         IAAI         4                 1
6        btn           0    protein3         ABBA         4                 2
7        btn           0    protein4         PGGP         4                 1
8        pgm           1    protein1         IAAI         4                 1
9        pgm           1    protein2         PGGP         4                 2
10       pgm           1    protein3         KIIK         4                 1
11       pgm           1    protein4         PGGP         4                 2
12       btn           1    protein1         ABBA         4                 2
13       btn           1    protein2         IAAI         4                 1
14       btn           1    protein3         ABBA         4                 2
15       btn           1    protein4         PGGP         4                 1
```

What I've tried so far that works is

```
counts = df.groupby(['Category', 'Shuffled'])['Sequence'].value_counts()
```

which gives me

```
Category    Shuffled    Sequence
pgm         0           PGGP        2
                        IAAI        1
                        KIIK        1
            1           PGGP        2
                        IAAI        1
                        KIIK        1
btn         0           ABBA        2
                        IAAI        1
                        PGGP        1
            1           ABBA        2
                        IAAI        1
                        PGGP        1
```

These are the values I want, but how do I get them in their own row in the original dataframe?

Comment: df.groupby(['Category', 'Shuffled'])['Sequence'].transform('count')

Comment: @YOBEN_S this gives me all 4's in the sequence_counts column in the above example. It appears to only count how many sequences there are total in a category/shuffled group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df['Sequence_count'] = df.groupby(['Category', 'Shuffled','Sequence'])['Sequence'].transform('count')
```